# Integral of $x^{\sqrt x}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to find this integral:
$$\int x^\sqrt x \, dx $$

Wolframalpha gave me an integral. (So it does exist)

I tried integration by parts & tried converting it to $$ e^{\sqrt x \ln(x)} $$ then expanding $e$ by its summation notation.

Comment: I suppose the question is not what the integral is, but more how to derive it?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yes! Exactly.

Comment: Wolfram didn't give you an integral. It doesn't exist in terms of elementary functions. It may have given you the result for a definite one.

Comment: @1over137, check the wolfram output. It gives you an indefinite integral closed form.

Comment: @1over137 How do you know it doesn't exist?

Comment: Because there is no function $f(x)$ whose derivative is that one. And I'm going to write down a result which is not a standard function. @Mario

Comment: @vrugtehagel then link us the output.

Comment: The link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E(sqrt(x)) and the integral you get: $\frac{x^{\sqrt{x}+1}}{\sqrt{x}+1}+c$. You might be confused with $\int x^x$

Comment: @vrugtehagel So why the derivative isn't the same? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Derivative+(x%5E(sqrt(x)%2B1))%2F(sqrt(x)%2B1) There is a bug in wolfram online calculator. I have mathematica 10.02 on my computer and it spits out nothing.

Comment: It seems that there is no answer. You may calculate only approximate answer by expanding the function.

Comment: This looks like a wolfram bug - it is treating the $\sqrt{x}$ exponent like a constant. i.e. it is using the result:$$\int x^{\sqrt{a}}dx=\frac{x^{\sqrt{a}+1}}{\sqrt{a}+1}+C$$with $a=x$

Comment: @Ali That's what I did. But I was hoping to derive that result wolfram gave.

Comment: @Mario - wolframs result is a bug - see my comment above. The actual result is much more complicated as shown by 1over below. Wolfram is known to have some bugs in it - it is not perfect :)

Comment: That what Wolfram is giving cannot be an answer since a derivative of $\frac{x^{\sqrt{x}+1}}{\sqrt{x}+1}$ cannot avoid having $\log$ in the result. It seems that Wolfram is treating $x$ in the power as a separate variable.

Comment: As you see in comments above it cannot be true it used $x$ as a constant such as $a$ in power.

Comment: WOLFRAM BUG ... the first one ever!!! (not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^{\sqrt{x}} = e^{\sqrt{x}\ln(x)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x}\ln(x))^k}{k!}$$

Thence you get

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \int \left(\sqrt{x}\ln(x)\right)^k\ \text{d}x$$

A repeated integration by parts gives:

$$\int \left(\sqrt{x}\ln(x)\right)^k\ \text{d}x = \Gamma\left[1 + \frac{k}{2},\ -\left(1 + \frac{k}{2}\right)\ln(x)\right]\ln^{1 + k/2}(x)\left(-\left(1 + \frac{k}{2}\right)\ln(x)\right)^{-1 - k/2}$$

So in the end we have

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\left(\Gamma\left[1 + \frac{k}{2},\ -\left(1 + \frac{k}{2}\right)\ln(x)\right]\ln^{1 + k/2}(x)\left(-\left(1 + \frac{k}{2}\right)\ln(x)\right)^{-1 - k/2}\right)$$

**Gamma Function**

More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) about the Gamma function

**Incomplete Gamma Function**

More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) about the incomplete Gamma Function (which is the used one)

Comment: (+1) I think this the best we can get here! I don't know but maybe Lambert function may come in use in this problem. :)

Comment: Thank you!! Well I did the same when I had to integrate $x^x$, but in that case it was quite easier, also because of the well known Sophomore's dream. I wonder if we may find a sort of convergence to some number too here!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: But how did you write k=0 in $$\sqrt x \ln(x)$$ ? (It'll be $$0*-\infty $$)

Comment: @Mario you can see it in the limit way: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x}\ln(x)= 0$$